# Server errors for AngularJS ng-fab-form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I am using validation on AngularJS side as well as serve side (e.g. for duplicate value check) and would like to expose these errors to users. Without [ng-fab-form](https://github.com/johannesjo/ng-fab-form) I was able to build custom server error directive and use it like this:

```
<input type="number" id="level" name="level" ng-model="vm.record.level"
  server-error
  required>
<div ng-messages="vm.form.role_level.$error">
  <p ng-message="server">{{ vm.errors.level }}</p>
</div>
```

But the goal of the library is to get rid of this kind of duplication. As you can see I am using *Controller as* syntax and assigning the errors to each field, when saving/updating the model fails:

```
angular.forEach(result.data.errors, function (errors, field) {
  vm.form[field].$setValidity('server', false);
  vm.errors[field] = errors.join(', ');
});
```

I customised [validation template](https://github.com/johannesjo/ng-fab-form#default-validations-and-creating-your-own-validation-template) to show messages for server error, however, I am not able to display dynamic error text. I suppose the problem is related to scope inheritance. Any ideas how could I achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 0):

I just found a way how to do it:

Add custom attribute, to hold the server error message value and watch the error in it.

```
<input type="number" id="level" name="level" ng-model="vm.record.level"
  validation="{{ vm.errors.level }}
  server-error
  required>
```

In validation template display the attribute value.

```
<li ng-message="server">{{ attrs.validation }}</li>
```

Comment: However, I would be interested in having cleaner solution than creating another watcher for each field...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using $asyncValidators instead of $setValidity from angular@1.3.2 on.

```
app.directive('username', function($q, $timeout) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
    var usernames = ['Jim', 'John', 'Jill', 'Jackie'];

      ctrl.$asyncValidators.username = function(modelValue, viewValue) {

        if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
          // consider empty model valid
          return $q.when();
        }

        var def = $q.defer();

        $timeout(function() {
          // Mock a delayed response
          if (usernames.indexOf(modelValue) === -1) {
            // The username is available
            def.resolve();
          } else {
            def.reject();
          }

        }, 2000);

        return def.promise;
      };
    }
  };
});
```

(example taken from the [docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/docs/guide/forms))

Then you could just add the message to your own validations template:

```
angular.module('exampleApp', [
    'ngFabForm'
])
    .config(function (ngFabFormProvider)
    {
        ngFabFormProvider.extendConfig({
            validationsTemplate : 'path/to/your-fabulous-validation-template.html'
        });
    });
```

And in the template add:

```
<li ng-message="username">I'm not valid!!! ;(</li>
```

There also was an issue about that on the github-page of the module: https://github.com/johannesjo/ng-fab-form/issues/34

For a cleaner solution there would have to be  an interface, which doesn't exist yet, but you could always [open an issue for that](https://github.com/johannesjo/ng-fab-form/issues/new).

Comment: While this is a valid approach, I am not trying to use only custom server validations (like the uniqueness check). I am trying to handle also situations in which for example I forget to set maxlength on html input and the server validations fails with error saying the value is too long.